# Elastic load balance between different clouds

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, azure

It it possible to have a load balancer on AWS distribute between an EC2 instance and an Azure virtual machine?

I want to mirror my app between both cloud platforms such that the Azure virtual machine is a weakly spec'd back-up that can be failed over to. However, I want the load balancer to request from it now and again in order to keep it warm.

Perhaps this is a bad idea and I should monitor the Azure machine with an automatic service.

Comment: Nop. Elastic load balancer only works for EC2 instances. You need to come up with a third-party solution or build your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Elastic Load Balancing automatically distributes incoming application traffic across multiple **Amazon EC2 instances** in the cloud.([link](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/))

As Bruno mention in the comment and from their official description, the answer is NO. And in my opinion, load balance will give better result if the instances are in the same private network so even if you build your own load balance that can handle different cloud services, the performance won't be as good as if you use instances from the same cloud service

Comment: Why should there be any difference in performance?

Comment: ... because its routing to a server elsewhere on the internet instead of on the same LAN?

Answer (score 6):

You might want to take a look at [Azure Traffic Manager](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/traffic-manager/) which is quite happy to load balance between 'on premises' and Azure - 'on premises' can certainly be an EC2 instance.

It is a little confused currently by their Service Management / Resource Management switch over. It might be a powershell only configuration, but it will certainly do what you require.

Answer (score 1):

Your situation can be easily addressed via DNS weighted round robin.

Run your infrastructure including a load balancer in both AWS and Azure. Use weighted DNS round-robin to serve most of your traffic via the AWS load balancer and a small portion via Azure. If you have to fail over then increase the Azure weight to 100 (after you've scaled up your capacity in Azure to cope of course).

Route53 can provide these features including health checking.

Comment: Makes sense, but doesn't updating DNS take a while to propagate?

Comment: It does, but you can set your DNS TTL as low as 60 seconds and ELB uses this technique behind the scenes the manage scaling and failover any way.